# How to refer to non-standard column names in DataFrames.jl

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a data table containing some columns that have spaces in their names. How I can reference these columns by name (e.g. `Column 1`) if I want to select just that column of the dataframe? I tried `data.Column 1` but this isn't workin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [DataFrames manual](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/latest/man/basics/#Basic-Operations-on-Data-Frames) mentions the many ways of indexing available. For eg.

```
julia> df."Column 1"
5-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5

julia> df[!, "Column 1"]
5-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

Comment: In general - in DataFrames.jl you can refer to columns using strings or `Symbol`s. This flexibility is allowed exactly with the intention to simplify working with column names containing characters that are not allowed in standard variable names in Julia.